# Dedicated bridge or second router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I've got a Linksys E4200 router upstairs.  This is a dual band router.  Connected to this router is a Western Digital 2TB NAS drive.

Downstairs I have a Western Digital TV Live media streamer.  When it's just me on the network I can stream movies fine from the NAS drive to the streamer downstairs but once the kids are on it with laptops / tablets / media streamer upstairs it starts to stutter and eventually just stops.  The streamer can only connect in the 2.4 GHz range.  Which is what just about everything else the network uses.

So I've had an idea, I was thinking about hooking up a second router / bridge downstairs which I would connect the streamer to with a CAT 6 cable.  Then connect the two routers on the 5 GHz wireless range.

My questions are:

1. Should this solve the problem because the 5 GHz range has less interference?
2. Is there a difference between getting a second router or getting an actual wireless
   bridge (eg Linksys WUMC710)?  Which would be better?

I know that I could use homeplugs and send the signal through the electrics but I would have to use an extension plug which I've heard degrades the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to comment but I ran out of space.

There's three things worth considering - firstly, that if you get a second router, it needs to run in client mode for what you want, and most routers don't support that out of the box. A router with openwrt or dd-wrt would be the safest bet. In this scenario, your router is acting *exactly* the way the bridge you are looking at works. In some cases the router may be cheaper, and a re-flashed router is about the most flexible bit of network gear you can have around.

Secondly, while 5ghz is less crowded, it also has a shorter range, so you may not be able to get a signal. Checking with another device that supports it first is a VERY good idea. Your slowness may not just be due to interference, but also too many people using wireless at once, so if you *have* the range, , *and* everyone is on 2.4 ghz, its worth a shot. I'd also suggest checking if you can get an N version of your bridge if you arn't intending to upgrade to AC soon, since its likely to be cheaper.

Finally, that passthrough homeplug units, which you can plug into a socket, and plug an extention cord exist, and should help with both noise reduction, and keeping sockets clear (I consider these a much better option than the mini adaptors which take up one socket for themselves). I suppose these are a little finicky but I've had decent luck once I set them up correctly (and realised one of my sockets was as noisy as a school tuckshop at recess).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Journeyman.  I've checked and I get a signal fine on the 5ghz range downstairs.  I've seen the passthrough plugs but that would mean I'd need to have a network cable going quite far (weird layout of the plugs at home). I'll take a look at finding an N version I won't be upgrading any time soon.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance - in a very similar situation, where I needed to extend wireless/wired access to a area with neither - I ended up going with homeplug and a spare DD-WRT acting as an access point/switch, and I considered many of these same issues in a horizontal fashion. The bridge does seem the most elegant option here.